# Website interface on 2 screens

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm making this website, and it's only gonna be opened on 2 screens at the same time. I'm going to generate a table with php with output from a database.

My goal is that if the table doesn't fit on the main screen it goes to the second screen. 
Is this even possible?

I've tried to come up with something but couldn't figure anything out. I have tried for loops but it has to do with the style and html or maybe javascript or jquery?

If this isn't possible should I generate a second window with jquery?

Thanks in advance!

```
if (!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
  $idArr = $_POST['check_list'];
  $id = $idArr[0];
  $parameters = array(':medId'=>$id);
  $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT naam FROM medewerkers WHERE medewerkerid = :medId");
  $sth->execute($parameters);
  while ($row = $sth->fetch())
  {
    echo "<h2>" . $row['naam'] . "</h2>";
  }


  ?>
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Donderdag <br> 31-05</th>
        <?php
          $datum = "2017-05-31";

          $parameters = array(':date'=>$datum,
                              ':aid'=>$id);
          $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT opdrachten.KRITISCHE_DATUM, opdrachten.PLANNINGS_DATUM, opdrachten.OPDRACHTID, onderzoekactiviteiten.A_UITVOERDER
                                FROM opdrachten
                                INNER JOIN onderzoekactiviteiten
                                ON opdrachten.OPDRACHTID=onderzoekactiviteiten.OPDRACHTID
                                WHERE PLANNINGS_DATUM = :date
                                AND A_UITVOERDER = :aid");
          $sth->execute($parameters);
          while ($row = $sth->fetch())
          {
            $cutKritDate = substr($row['KRITISCHE_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            $cutPlanDate = substr($row['PLANNINGS_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            echo "<td>Krit= " . $cutKritDate . "<br>";
            echo "Plan= " . $cutPlanDate . "<br>";
            echo "Opdracht= " . $row['OPDRACHTID'] . "</td>";
          }

        ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Vrijdag <br> 02-06</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Maandag <br> 03-06</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Dinsdag <br> 04-06</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Woensdag <br> 05-06</th>
      </tr>
  </table>


  <?php
}
else
{
  $check_list = NULL;
  $id = NULL;
  echo "U bent vergeten een medewerker aan te vinken.";
}
```

I have a form with names, if one is selected it generates a table. this is how I generate the table. The goal is that the tables are below each other. But when it doesn't fit anymore (when you can scroll) the table needs to go to the second screen.

Comment: why share your code for better help?

Comment: @ehsan I'v added the code

Comment: it's up to the user how wide they make their browser window. But if you know how wide the two screens are (at the resolution they're normally displayed at), and you can assume the user will always open their browser across the full width of both, then you can use CSS to allow your site to expand to that width.

Comment: @ADyson yes thats the case, how can I do that with CSS?

Comment: set the width property of the page body. Or probably if you don't set any width at all it'll just be as wide as the browser. Of course if you use block level elements which naturally go to the next line you either need to switch them for inline ones, or float them, or use something like flexbox.